# how to slicing csv file using python's panda

Tags: python, pandas

I have this csv file:

```
DATE        RELEASE 10GB    100GB   200GB   400GB   600GB   800GB   1000GB
5/5/16  2.67    0.36        4.18    8.54    18      27      38      46
5/5/16  2.68        0.5     4.24        9.24        18      27      37      46
5/6/16  2.69        0.32        4.3     9.18        19      29      37      46
5/6/16  2.7     0.35        4.3     9.3     19      28      37      46
5/6/16  2.71        0.3     4.1     8       8.18    16  24      33      41
```

I need to calculate the difference of each column (10 GB ~ 1000GB)between release 2.71 and release 2.70. That means last row - the row above.

My code to access each desired row are: `row1=df[df.RELEASE == 2.70], and row2 = df[df.RELEASE == 2.71]`

My issue is: I do not know how to access each element. I try to put the row1 and row2 into list. list(row1), list(row2), but that only print the title rather than the value of each cell.

My question is: how do I acces each element of desired row, so I can calculat: `"0.3 -0.35"` Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its really the last two rows you're chasing try out negative indexing
   df.loc[-1,:] - df.loc[-2,:]

I'm on a phone so haven't run the code but it should get you closer.